# How to call a route within a route in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, api

As you can see from the question i am a beginner in Nods js writing apis. 
I wrote an api that returns all courses info of a student

```
CourseModel.findbyId(){}
```

Now i want to write another api that returns student info + his courses info.

```
StudentModel.findbyId(){}
```

My question is can i reuse my old courses api inside student api? or do i have to write all the courses logic again inside student api

i tried to google it but couldn't find something useful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "replicate" the logic the proper way would be to call a function from within the route.

A very psuedoi example:

```
app.get("/course", getCourses);
app.get("/student", getStudent);

function getCoursesWithLogic() {
   return CourseModel.findbyId(){}
}

async function getCourses(req, res){
    let courses = await getCoursesWithLogic();
}

async function getStudent(req, res){
    let student = await StudentModel.findbyId();
    let courses = await getCoursesWithLogic();
}
```

In theory you can also not define `getCoursesWithLogic` and just call `getCourses` from within `getStudent` but thats a bit "hacky".

Comment: hi thanks for your answer,,,,
in getStudent function, 
console.log(courses) returned undefined

but getCoursesWithLogic works fine
can you solve it?

Comment: You need to give an objectID for getById method  for it to return a document.